# How can you reload a ViewController after dismissing a modally presented view controller in Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a first tableViewController which opens up a second tableViewcontroller upon clicking a cell. The second view controller is presented modally (Show Detail segue) and is dismissed with:

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {})
```

At this point, the second view controller slides away and reveals the first view controller underneath it. I would then like to reload the first view controller. I understand that this may require use of delegate functions, but not sure exactly how to implement it

Comment: Call `-reloadData` on your `UITableView` inside `-viewDidAppear`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it a bit differently since I don't want that dependancy.

And this approach is intended when you present a controller modally, since the presenting controller wont reload when you dismiss the presented.

Anyway solution!

Instead you make a Singleton (mediator)

```
protocol ModalTransitionListener {
    func popoverDismissed()
}

class ModalTransitionMediator {
    /* Singleton */
    class var instance: ModalTransitionMediator {
        struct Static {
            static let instance: ModalTransitionMediator = ModalTransitionMediator()
        }
        return Static.instance
    }

private var listener: ModalTransitionListener?

private init() {

}

func setListener(listener: ModalTransitionListener) {
    self.listener = listener
}

func sendPopoverDismissed(modelChanged: Bool) {
    listener?.popoverDismissed()
}
}
```

Have you Presenting controller implement the protocol like this:

```
class PresentingController: ModalTransitionListener {
//other code
func viewDidLoad() {
    ModalTransitionMediator.instance.setListener(self)
}
//required delegate func
func popoverDismissed() {
    self.navigationController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    yourTableViev.reloadData() (if you use tableview)
}
}
```

and finally in your PresentedViewController in your viewDid/WillDisappear func or custom func add:

```
ModalTransitionMediator.instance.sendPopoverDismissed(true)
```

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 5:**

You can access the presenting ViewController (presentingViewController) property and use it to reload the table view when the view will disappear.

```
class: FirstViewController {
    var tableView: UITableView

    present(SecondViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

In your second view controller, you can in the viewWillDisappear method, add the following code:

```
class SecondViewController {
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        if let firstVC = presentingViewController as? FirstViewController {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                firstVC.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When you dismiss the SecondViewController, the tableview of the FirstViewController will reload.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Very Precise Solution, you saved my day

Comment: In my case, presentingViewController is SecondViewController. Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 4):

You can simply reaload your data in `viewDidAppear:`, but that might cause the table to be refreshed unnecessarily in some cases.

A more flexible solution is to use protocols as you have correctly guessed.

Let's say the class name of your first tableViewController is `Table1VC` and the second one is `Table2VC`. You should define a protocol called `Table2Delegate` that will contain a single method such as `table2WillDismissed`.

```
protocol Table2Delegate {
    func table2WillDismissed()
}
```

Then you should make your `Table1VC` instance conform to this protocol and reload your table within your implementation of the delegate method.

Of course in order for this to work, you should add a property to `Table2VC` that will hold the delegate:

```
weak var del: Table2Delegate?
```

and set its value to your `Table1VC` instance.

After you have set your delegate, just add a call to the delegate method right before calling the `dismissViewControllerAnimated` in your `Table2VC` instance.

```
del?.table2WillDismissed()
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {})
```

This will give you precise control over when the table will get reloaded.

Comment: The behaviour of the OS is the same regardless of the language you use.

Comment: It looks nicer if you do it in the viewWillAppear; as the table appears loaded already. if you do it in the viewDidAppear; you'll get the table and after a fraction of time it will get loaded. And yes swift also calls viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear after dismissing the view controller

Comment: override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        // code I want to execute
    }

Worked perfectly for me