# Reload tableView after dismiss a viewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a ViewController(VCA) with a TableView inside. From this ViewController it is possibile to call another ViewController (VCB). In this second VC it is possibile add an item to the plist used to populate the TableView in VCA. The problem is that when I save the new item and dismiss the VCB, I can't reload the TableView in VCA.

I have found a lot of examples:

[How can you reload a ViewController after dismissing a modally presented view controller in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28706877/how-can-you-reload-a-viewcontroller-after-dismissing-a-modally-presented-view-co)

[How to call reload table view after you call dismissViewController in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31684954/how-to-call-reload-table-view-after-you-call-dismissviewcontroller-in-swift)

[How to reload tableview from another view controller in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25921623/how-to-reload-tableview-from-another-view-controller-in-swift)

[Update the data of a TableViewController after add item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33161429/update-the-data-of-a-tableviewcontroller-after-add-item)

[Update the first view after dismissing Popover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42661129/update-the-first-view-after-dismissing-popover)

[Table view is not getting updated after dismissing the popover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37119298/table-view-is-not-getting-updated-after-dismissing-the-popover)

after reading i tried with this code:

```
    **IN VCB**

import UIKit 

protocol AddItemDelegateProtocol {
    func didAddItem()
}

class VCB: UIViewController {

    var delegate : AddItemDelegateProtocol?
    ...
}

@IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any) {
        .... 
   self.delegate?.didAddItem()
   dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)     
   }



**In VCA**

class VCA: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, AddItemDelegateProtocol {

let addItemVC = VCB()
...

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        addItemVC.delegate = self
        ...
    }

func didAddItem() {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

but this doesn't work. I don't
understand where I'm wrong. Could
you help me?

**EDIT: my Solution**
I solved in this way:

I've created a singleton in which I declare:

```
    class DataManager {

        static let shared = DataManager()
        var firstVC = VCA()
.....
}
```

then, **in viewDidLoad of VCA**:

```
DataManager.shared.firstVC = self
```

now, **in the saveButton of VCB**, i can call:

```
@IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any) {
    ........
    DataManager.shared.firstVC.tableView.reloadData()
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: How you are moving to this VCB ? Show the code of it

Comment: whit a simply connection from a button in VCA

Comment: @Aravind A R thanks for the tips

Comment: Your solution fixed my problem! Thanks for the tip

Comment: happy to have been useful

Answer (score 2):

you can do this in two way :-

1)
 Do One thing in VCA

**VCA**

```
   override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool){
       tableView.reloadData()
   }
```

If this does not work out then try this.

2)
create an instance of VCA in VCB and whenever you move from VCA to VCB pass the value of VCA to the instance of VCB and from there reload the table.

**VCB**

```
    var instanceOfVCA:VCA!    // Create an instance of VCA in VCB

   func saveButton(){
    instanceOfVCA.tableView.reloadData()  // reload the table of VCA from the instance
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) 
  }
```

**VCA**

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any!) {
  VCB.instanceOfVCA = self   // Pass the value of VCA in instance of VCB while navigating through segue
}
```

Comment: Hi @Ayush sharma, i've edited my question with the solution that works for me. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

Here you are calling table's reload data when the viewcontroller is not yet shown. i.e, Even before you dismissed the viewcontroler VCB and viewcontroller VCA is shown, you are calling reloadData. 
Try calling reload data in VCA's `viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)` function.

Comment: Unfortunately, i don't understand why, after dismiss the VCA doesn't recall viewWillAppear.

Comment: If you are showing VCB from VCA, then after dismissing VCB, VCA's viewWillAppear will be called

Comment: Hi @Aravind A R, probably i make some mistake, i'm a newbie. but i found a solution that I have added under my question. Thank you for your time

Comment: No, viewWillAppear doesn't gets called, after dismissing vcb even if it was presented fron vca

Answer (score 0):

Try this: make changes as below

```
let addItemVC : VCB? = nil
```

**In ViewDidLoad**

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            addItemVC = (storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerID") as! SelectionViewController?)! // change ViewControllerID with your controller id
            addItemVC.delegate = self

    }
```

Comment: i have checked your code . it is working with this solution.

Comment: Hi @KKRocks, i've edited my question with the solution i found. thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

The code in your question is perfectly good. I use the same approach and it works like a charm.
IMHO the problem in your code is that you only refresh the table view with **self.tableView.reloadData()**, BUT may be you forget to **refresh your data model** - the data source for the table view. E.g. if you delete an entity from Core Data then you need to refetch your data and only after that reload the table view.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, i solved using a singleton

Comment: Yes, I know. I posted it, because that was my issue. May be it’ll help somebody who face the similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it using delegate/protocol that is usually used to pass data between view controllers but in this instance I just called the function without passing data and inside this function i put ( tableView.reloadData() ) and it worked like a sweet :)

juts google "Passing data between view controllers and use the method as I explained above"