# firebase dismiss reload table in Swift?

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase, reloaddata

I have 3 viewControllers:

VcA: I read data with observers from database and pass with segue to VcB.

VcB: I read data and display it, with a button I call VcC to update data passing data with segue.

VcC: a STATIC tableview in which I update data and save them.

The problem is that when I dismiss after saved VcC and go back in VcB all data is old, even if in firebase all data are perfectly updated.

In VcB for example I read the Title like this:

```
 var groupName: String?
```

than in didAppear:

```
 Name.title = groupName
```

Anyway if I also go back from VcB to VcC all data of the table are the old data.

To be more clear:

I call the database in VcA

[image]

click the name in the table and pass the data to Vcb, all is fine for now, title and other vars are ok

[image]

now I click EDIT and call to VcC, the table where I update the data, make change and save,

[image]

after save VcC dismiss and I go back to VcB -> title is still p2 but in firebase not!

[image]

I click again on EDIT to return to VcC (the edit table), title is the old one

[image]

I think that I have to recall data from db... anyway to do it without refresh the data from firebase?

I know that if I go back to VcA after save all is fine but I really need to go to VcB, how can I do?

I found many threads, this is the most similar but not exact situation...
[Reload tableView after dismiss a viewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44517304/reload-tableview-after-dismiss-a-viewcontroller)

Comment: Could you provide the code of the VcB where you're trying to read the data?

Comment: Use a `delegate`. You'll be able to call reloadData from VcC when you go back to VcB.

Comment: @Woof I added how I read the code

Comment: @HaVaNa7 I still don't see the code of the VcB with fetching the data base. Add it please to your question

Answer (score 0):

If I can follow this correctly.

VcC:

```
protocol %NAME%Delegate
{
    func reloadData()
}


class VcC: UIViewController /*(or table)*/{
    var mDelegate : %NAME%Delegate?


    //in the func you use to dismiss self (VcC)
    //mDelegate?. reloadData()

}
```

VcB:

```
class VcB: UIViewController /* (or table)*/,%NAME%Delegate  {
    func reloadData(){
       tableView.reloadData()
       //OR
       //Observer for Firebase here to gather the new information. Make sure to reset all datasources if you do this.
    }
}
```

Comment: thnx but  in VcB I have a simple ViewController not a table, the table is in VcC only

Comment: It’ll work regardless. I just didn’t know which class to add. It’ll work with ‘view’ and ‘table’.

Comment: I did it but when I arrive at VcB the title is still the old one maybe a problem with my dismiss method?
 _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

Comment: Make sure you're calling `mDelegate?.reloadData()` before the dismiss method.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them

Here is a perfect example of what you are trying to accomplish. Very detailed answer.